# ¿Por qué me sale este error en el Update? Con Java y MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, update

Estoy intentando modificar una tabla de MySQL con Java y tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
String editSQL="UPDATE PARTESDETRABAJO SET DESCRIPCIONTAREA=?,"+"FECHAENTRADA=?,"+"FECHAENTREGA=?,"+"TIEMPOEMPLEADO=?,"+"WHERE NPARTE='"+sesion.getAttribute("ENparte")+"'";
```

He creado el try en el que he metido el preparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conexion.prepareStatement(editSQL);
```

He intento modififcar los campos de la tabla:

```
pst.setString(5,descripcion);
pst.setString(6, fechaentrada);
pst.setString(7, fechaentrega);
pst.setString(8,tiempo);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Pero al hacerlo me sale es siguiente error y no sé a qué es debido:

> Error: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number
>   of parameters, which is 4)

Gracias por vuestra ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Solo tienes 4 parametros y estas asignando valores a las posiciones 5, 6, 7 y 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que asignas valores a posiciones inexitentes en el PS.

Haciendolo así debería funcionarte

```
pst.setString(1,descripcion); 
pst.setString(2, fechaentrada); 
pst.setString(3, fechaentrega); 
pst.setString(4,tiempo);
```

Comment: Es que los campos están en esas posiciones, los primeros campos no los quiero modificar.

Comment: Estas confunciendo cosas, la posicion que le indicas no es la de la BBDD sino de la query.

Comment: Ya me he dado cuenta. Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce al intentar guardar un valor en una posición del `PreparedStatement` que no existe.

Tu `PreparedStatement` tiene **4 parámetros** y en tu ejemplo estás intentando guardar datos en las posiciones 5, 6, 7 y 8, que no existen.

Puedes probar con con:

```
pst.setString(1, descripcion);
pst.setString(2, fechaentrada);
pst.setString(3, fechaentrega);
pst.setString(4, tiempo);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Los preparedStatement empiezan en 1 no en 0, aqui no hay ningun array. https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Comment: Vaya, pensaba que seguían la misma estructura de un array, edito mi respuesta. Siempre se aprende algo nuevo. Gracias @JDev!